# How to stop changing of color when hovering over button in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

iI don't want to change the color to anything else. I want the button to not change color to the light grey color when hovering over it. Is there any way to do it in Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

button = Button(window, text="ok", fg='white', bg='black')

button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04 by the way

Comment: On Windows, with python 3.6.5, a normal tkinter button does not change color when hovering over it. Can you share some code that exhibits this behaviour and share which OS you are using?

Comment: i assume your using `ttk` button, instead use a `tk` button for normal effects

Comment: Configure the `activebackground` color to the same as `bg` color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `activeforeground` color to the same as `fg` color and `activebackground` color to the same as `bg` color:

```
button = Button(window, text="ok", fg='white', bg='black',
                activeforeground='white', activebackground='black')
```